# Contract deployed address

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses

Is there a way to save the deployed contract address into a variable. Something related to a constructor that save the deployed address into the variable?

Comment: You mean `address(this)` in Solidity?

Comment: Im going to test

Comment: Why save it? You can get it in any function of the contract at any time. Saving `address(this)` into a state-variable and then using that state-variable every time you need it is going to be a lot more expensive than simply fetching `address(this)` into a local variable every time you need it.